# Python using RegEx to search a webpage for a match in a list

Tags: python, regex, list, selenium

So the end goal here would be to identify a match to any item in my list while web crawling in Selenium. It's probably a silly syntax error.

Code:

```
criteriainactive = ['Inactive', 'Deleted', 'Terminated', 'Banned', 'Suspended']
statuscheck = re.search(criteriainactive,src)
```

Traceback:

```
return _cache[type(pattern), pattern, flags]

TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Please let me know if there is any other way to search for the above list in a webpage. Thanks in advance  :)

Comment: Search for each item individually?

Comment: Scott, I have it structured like that currently. It works, but in future use if the list is longer, it would be very nice to have knowledge of a feature like this to further condense the code.

Comment: `re.search` take a string or a regex object as argument, not a list.
`x = re.search("^some string$", txt) `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`re.search` takes a string or a regex object as argument, not a list. You can use something like:

```
import re
criteriainactive = ['Inactive', 'Deleted', 'Terminated', 'Banned', 'Suspended']
for x in criteriainactive:
    statuscheck = re.search(x, src)
    print(x, statuscheck)
```

Comment: This did the trick. Thank you for further clarifying why it didn't work as well!

Answer (score 0):

`re.search` takes a regex pattern as it's first argument, not a list. You can search for either of the elements by doing something like

```
pattern = f'({"|".join(criteriainactive)})'
re.search(pattern,scr)
```